# Angular 4 not setting headers correctly or Express.js not looking in the right spot?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, express, http-headers

I'm sending an auth token in my request headers to an Express.js API, when I make the request in postman with a header named 'Authorization' it works perfectly but when I send it with angular 4 like so:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  .set('Authorization', `${token}`);
this.http.get<Response>(`${this.apiURL}dashboard/`, { headers: headers })
  .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

When logged the headers object looks to be setting them correctly however when I try to retrieve the token in my express route like so:

```
const token = req.get('Authorization');
```

It is always undefined. What is angular doing differently from postman?
[image: Headers Object]

Result when I try to log the token:
[image: bad result]

Postman working:
[image: postman working]

[image]

Comment: You need to add 'Bearer ' before the token

Comment: @DinoMyte I will try that.

Comment: @DinoMyte Still undefined.

Comment: you need to add withCredentials: true as an option

Comment: Have you looked at the header case? The RFC says it is case-insensitive but some libs treat Authorization != authorization. I know early beta versions of Angular had an issue with that. 
Try const token = req.get('authorization');

Comment: @YannVo I have tried that

Comment: @evayly .set('withCredentials': true)?

Comment: @BirdDad {withCredentials: true, headers: headers}

Comment: @evayly still undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer, contrary to the express.js docs telling me to use: `req.get('Authorization')` I found that if i use `req.headers['Authorization']` it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

`HttpHeaders` objects are immutable. Check out https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders
Try setting headers like this

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('Authorization', 'token');
```

Comment: I'm not re-assigning headers, if i was it would break because its also a const which its not doing, I have tried that way as well and it doesn't fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting headers like this
**For Angular versions < 5**

```
        import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";

        // inside your Class
        headers = new Headers({
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "q=0.8;application/json;q=0.9",
                "Authorization": "token"
        });
        options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
```

and pass this.options along with your http request.

**For Angular version 5**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
};
```

and pass httpOptions along with your http request.

Comment: No change, I'm starting to think they are setting correctly and I'm just missing something else.

Comment: router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.get('Authorization');
  console.log(token);
  // undefined unless i use postman
}

Comment: Can you please let me know which angular version you are using?

Comment: I am using angular 5.2

Comment: Try angular 5 version of my answer.